# Random symbols instead of output in assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

Here is the code:

```
model tiny  
.code  
 .startup  
      mov dx, offset tm  
      mov ah, 0ah  
      int 21h  
      mov dx, offset testm  
      mov ah, 09h  
      int 21h  
      mov dx, offset tm  
      add dx, 2h  
      mov ah, 09h  
      int 21h  
      ret  
 tm db 255, 255, 255 dup ("$")  
 testm db "Entered string: $"  
End
```

it should just output the entered string but instead of it shows the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jMEv.png

i'm using TASM compiler and DosBox

Comment: You forgot to initialize `ds`.

Comment: Jester is correct since you generated an EXE file, however in your case if you want to generate an EXE file and have TASM do the proper segment initialization with the `.startup` directive you can change `model tiny` to `model small` and put your data in the `.data` segment. With `tiny` it made an assumption that you would generate a COM program. If you wanted to use `tiny` you could have linked with the `/t` option (TLINK) to create a COM program rather than EXE.